# How to see unused hardrive space?

Tags: partitioning, grub2, system-installation, mount, hard-drive

Just installed 2TB nvme hard drive and did a default Ubuntu server install. When I run df -H I only see about 136G. Here is my output:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              6.3G  3.2M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   26G   68G  28% /
tmpfs                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.0G  254M  1.6G  14% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.1G  6.1M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              6.3G  4.0K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Can someone explain how to see the rest of my hardrive? I am new to linux.

*edit:*
@Marco answered my question in comments:

Here is pvscan results:

```
PV /dev/nvme0n1p3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [<1.82 TiB / <1.72 TiB free]
Total: 1 [<1.82 TiB] / in use: 1 [<1.82 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1 print

```
Model: WD_BLACK SN850X 2000GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32              boot, esp
 2      1128MB  3276MB  2147MB  ext4
 3      3276MB  2000GB  1997GB
```

Comment: Would this be an Ubuntu *Server* installation? The `vg-ubuntu--lv` is pointing to a logical volume being used, which is common on server installations. The idea is generally that the initial LV is for the system, then the admin will create additional volumes that are dedicated to specific purposes. This way, in the event a server needs an OS to be reinstalled, there is less chance of losing data.

Comment: Please add the output of `pvscan` and `parted /dev/nvme0n1 print` to your question.

Comment: Generally; if you're new to Linux, begin with a non-server install and get better acquainted with the OS.

Comment: @matigo This sounds like the answer, I did not know that about vg-ubuntu--lv. Thanks.

Comment: @Marco This is also the answer to my question of how can I see the rest of my hardrive. Thanks.